# Python - Simple TCP/IP S/C: Not all strings converted error for a print statement

Tags: python, tcp, client, server, aptana

Okay so i was setting up a simple socket TCP/IP server and client, and now i'm getting this error in, PyDev, inside Aptana Atudio 3. Server runs fine and waits for connection, but my client when ran give me the error

**print 'establishing connection to server at %s ' % server_address**

**TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**

Ive gone to my normal resource before stack for trying to problem solve myself, and compared my code with the articles at [PYMOTW](http://www.pymotw.com) and adjusted to match theirs and see if it changed my errors. I cant seem to see whats causing the error. I have my interpreter set to the same language of python as my pc is running... Heres my code,i've searched questions asked by other users with the same issue, but it always seems theres a fix for theirs that isnt working for me..

```
import socket
import sys


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # @UndefinedVariable

server_address = ('localhost', 0)
print 'establishing connection to server at %s' % server_address
sock.connect(input(server_address))  # @UndefinedVariable

try:
    message = 'message to server'
    print 'sending %s' % message
    sock.sendall(message) 

    amount_recieved = 0 
    amount_expected = len(message)  # @UndefinedVariable

    while amount_recieved < amount_expected:
        data = sock.recv(16)
        amount_recieved += len(data)  # @UndefinedVariable
        print 'recieved %s' %(data)
finally:
    print 'closing down'
    sock.close
```

()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`server_address` is a tuple.  Try this:

```
print 'establishing connection to server at %s ' % str(server_address)
```

or this:

```
print 'establishing connection to server at %s:%d ' % server_address
```

Comment: Weird, i tried it once before, and it gave the same error saying str was invalid, but now its working. Thanks!